# spring cloud consul high cpu in a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, cpu-usage, spring-cloud, consul

I setup a Spring boot application with `@EnableDiscoveryClient` and using Consul as the cloud provider. I noticed that this generates high cpu consumption due to `ConsulCatalogWatch.catalogServicesWatch`. Looking at the code, I noticed that the annotation

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${spring.cloud.consul.discovery.catalogServicesWatchDelay:10}")
```

will cause this method to be call at a very high rate.
Does anyone have met this and am I missing something ?

Comment: Then why not simply reconfigure that property to another value...

Comment: This is part of the Spring Cloud consul code, I'm just wondering about the default value of 10ms

Comment: Yeah, that is a low number, I'll fix that.

Comment: The good thing is you can change that value as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, set `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.catalogServicesWatchDelay=30000`.

Fixed via [issue 94](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/94).